# Thread 1: EXC_BAD_INSTRUCTION (code=EXC_I386_INVOP, subcode=0x0) Swift

Tags: ios, swift

I am trying to switch from one view to another but I get this error and I do not know why am i getting the error.

i used this function to go to next controller:

```
   func showChatControllerForGroup(_ user: [User], groupName: String) {

        let vc: GroupChatMessangingViewController = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "GroupChatMessangingViewController") as! GroupChatMessangingViewController
//it crashed above here

        vc.group?.members = user
        vc.group?.name = groupName
        self.navigationController?.pushViewController(vc, animated: true)

}
```

to call this, i call it at another view at:

```
var group: Group? {
    didSet {
        navigationItem.title = group?.name
    }
}

var chosenUser: [User] = []
let user = self.chosenUser

  override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = UIBarButtonItem(title: "Create", style: .plain, target: self, action: #selector(createGroup))

    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
}

 @objc func createGroup(){

    let transition = CATransition()
    transition.duration = 0.5
    transition.timingFunction = CAMediaTimingFunction(name: kCAMediaTimingFunctionEaseInEaseOut)
    transition.type = kCATransitionReveal
    transition.subtype = kCATransitionFromBottom
    navigationController?.view.layer.add(transition, forKey: nil)
    _ = navigationController?.popViewController(animated: true)
    let user = self.chosenUser
    self.nextVC.showChatControllerForGroup(user, groupName: groupNameTextField.text!) }
```

just in case if anyone needs to see my User class:

```
class User {
var id: String?
var name: String?
var email: String?
var profileImageUrl: String?
var lastMessage: String?
var timestamp: String? //reason why this exist was because in mainmenu, we appended users, not msssage

init() {

}

init(dictionary: [String: AnyObject]) {
    self.id = dictionary["id"] as? String
    self.name = dictionary["name"] as? String
    self.email = dictionary["email"] as? String
    self.profileImageUrl = dictionary["profileImageUrl"] as? String
}
```

}

as of my Group class:

```
class Group {
var id: String?
var name: String?
var members: [User]!
var groupImageUrl: String?
var lastMessage: String?
var timestamp: String?

init() {

}

init(dictionary: [String: AnyObject]) {
    self.id = dictionary["id"] as? String
    self.name = dictionary["name"] as? String
}}
```

Is there any reason why is it crashing?

Comment: on the Group class try to change the members from var members: [User]! to var members: [User] = []

Comment: done, still crash on same place

Comment: ok then on showChatControllerForGroup try to initialise again the storyboard with the storyboard name it has and call the GroupChatMessangingViewController not with the self.storyboard? but with the new variable

Answer (score 0):

My guess is you in

```
    let vc: GroupChatMessangingViewController = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "GroupChatMessangingViewController") as! GroupChatMessangingViewController
```

you are calling the wrong storyboard. Check and see if you are in the right storyboard.

Comment: ok got it! thanks. Am just wondering I only have one storyboard, why isnt self. is correct...But thx anyway

Comment: added   let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)